# Singletons, Static methods and webservice scalability

Tags: asp.net, web-services, singleton, scalability, static-methods

I have a webservice running with asp net and mvc4 api.

For each request, I have a controller, for example:
GetUserData, GetStates, etc.

Each of these controller access a Manager class (which is a singleton) to retrieve data from. All the methods in the Manager class are context free and independent.

```
public class StatesController : ApiController
{
    public List<StateModel> Get()
    {            
        return Manager.Instance.GetStates();
    }
}
```

I was told that this is not good for the scalability of the web application. How should I circumvent this?
Should I make those methods static in the Manager class? Should I move the entire method to the controller class? Should a make the constructor public and instantiate the Manager class everytime (the Manager class has almost no properties and fields, only a bunch o methods)? There is some better approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to explain this at a very high level, but one approach would be to relocate your `GetStates()` logic to its own class -- i.e. a `StateRepository` or something similar. Perhaps you build a couple of interfaces around this "repository" concept:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> All();
}

public interface IStateRepository : IRepository<State>
{
    IEnumerable<State> All();
}
```

And now implement your repository:

```
public class StateRepository : IStateRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<State> All()
    {
        // retrieve states from file/DB/service etc.
    }
}
```

Now we move on to the next concept: Dependency Injection (DI). Somehow you need to get your controller an instance of the `StateRepository`, but we want to maintain low coupling. DI allows you to do this quite nicely. Once set up, your controller looks like this:

```
public class StatesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IStateRepository _stateRepository;

    public StatesController(IStateRepository stateRepository)
    {
        _stateRepository = stateRepository;
    }

    public List<StateModel> Get()
    {            
        return _stateRepository.All();
    }
}
```

There's a small amount of work to incorporate DI inject your WebApi, but once that's done, you'll have a single line of code such as (e.g. [Ninject syntax]):

```
Bind<IStateRepository>().To<StateRepository>().InRequestScope();
                                       // or  .InSingletonScope();
```

Now anytime your controller is invoked, a new (request scope) or existing (singleton scope) instance of your `StateRepository` is automatically passed ("injected") to its constructor.

This approach is generally considered to be more scalable. Want to mock some data for unit tests? Create a `MockedStateRepository` that implements `IStateRepository` and change your binding. Want to use `IStateRepository` all over your app? Easy. Future maintenance is easier. The list goes on and on but perhaps you should do that research on your own.

Comment: Thank you, your response was very clear, but I have a question:
Lets say I'm inside the UserDataController and I need the list of states, today I just call the singleton to answer me with the states list. How should I proceed in this case for the solution you suggested?

Comment: You'd simply change or add a constructor to your `UserDataController` that takes an `IStateRepository` and use it the same way as your web API controller. The hard work is the initial setup of your DI container. Usually installing the package for it through NuGet makes it easier (Unity, Ninject, etc.).